# How to remove indicator that a NSTextField selected when editing is finished

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

When a editable  NSTextField is selected Cocoa marks it as a default by making a blue rectangular around the text field.

But when editing ended the indicator can not be removed unless another text field has been selected.

To remove selection indicator what should we do ?

We are using following function to detect the editing's end.

```
 override func controlTextDidEndEditing(notification: NSNotification) {

   // doing things like getting the string user has been made.

   }
```

Comment: Even if I tried **anotherTextField.becomeFirstResponder()**, **textField.resignFirstResponder** nothing has been changed.

Comment: Why not simply set the first responder of the window to `nil` which deselects the text field?

Answer (score 6):

`NSTextField` by default draws Focus Ring to show active state. If you want to remove it, you can set t to none.

```
override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
    textField.focusRingType = .none
}
```

**Note** The `NSTextField` is still the first Responder, If user start typing again, the focus ring will not turn to blue. This is because you have programatically changed it. To get it back, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: The rectangle (ring)  is removed by this function but the string the user has been entered is still marked by blue background colour.

Comment: try `NSApp.mainWindow?.makeFirstResponder(self)` instead of `textField.focusRingType = .none`

Comment: Yes this has been made it. But why it is not normally removed after new string entered. I think this is a bug.

Comment: Focus ring is used to show which outlet is currently active. When you press enter key to end editing, the responder is still the same TextField unless you click any other part of view heirarchy. This is not a bug.

Answer (score 5):

On your Xcode, select your Textfield -> Focus ring -> change from Default to None.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`textField.window?.makeFirstResponder(self)`

Comment: What is `self` here? Why not `nil` or `textField.window`?

Comment: self is view controller.

Comment: And what reason do you have to believe that the view controller accepts first responder? See the [docs for `makeFirstResponder()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419366-makefirstresponder).

Comment: You're right. I must be NSResponder. So it could be self.view or nil. [This doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSResponder) is more useful for this. Interesting that my code works. Maybe some check are inside and self used as nil.

Comment: An `NSViewController` is-a `NSResponder`, so that's not a problem. It's just that it's unlikely to accept first responder. A subclass of `NSViewController` would have to override `acceptsFirstResponder` to return true and do something meaningful with key events. `makeFirstResponder` will still work, but you're not supposed to call it unless the new first responder accepts it. And if you pass a responder which isn't prepared to deal with key events you may get bad results. Certainly not better than passing `nil`.